# PhoneGap buttons linked to function are not reponding

Tags: javascript, html, function, cordova, button

I am working on a Calculator PhoneGap Application, but i can't get the button with function attached to them to work. I don't see what it stop it. Also the buttons do work in PC browsers but not on the a phone(Tested: Blackberry, Android). If any know how to fix this please let me know thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MinDark.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<style>
table {table-layout:fixed}
td {width:25%}
#td1 {width:75%}
#td2 {width:25%}
</style>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header">
<a href="index.html" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right">Home</a>
<h5 style="text-transform:uppercase">Basic Calculator</h5>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<form name="calc">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td id="td1"><input type="text" name="cal" id="inbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="td2"><input type="button" value="="  onclick="equal()"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="calc.cal.value += '7'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="8" onclick="calc.cal.value += '8'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="calc.cal.value += '9'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="calc.cal.value += '+'"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="calc.cal.value += '4'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="calc.cal.value += '5'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="calc.cal.value += '6'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="calc.cal.value += '-'"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="calc.cal.value += '1'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="calc.cal.value += '2'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="calc.cal.value += '3'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="x" onclick="calc.cal.value += '*'"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="0" onclick="calc.cal.value += '0'"></td>   
    <td><input type="button" value="." onclick="calc.cal.value += '.'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="C" onclick="del()"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="÷" onclick="calc.cal.value += '/'"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function equal(){
    calc.cal.value = eval(calc.cal.value);
}
function del(){
    calc.cal.value = calc.cal.value.substring(0,-1)
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Update: I figured out what solves this from, the page needs to be reload after being open from the mainpage(index.html). I just don't know how to do that.

Solved: Add rel="external" to link.

Comment: this works perfectly for me(in android 3.2). Which is your cordova version?in which android version you are working?

Comment: not sure it was a friends

Comment: im not sure wat cordova, all i know is that i using github to upload the app and the phonegap build website